# Need optimized query or stored procedure for document management system

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on some document management system and need to provide document sharing feature to users. I have two tables one contains information of uploaded document(say Table 1) and other table contains information of document sharing with users(say Table 2).

Please see image below:
[image]

Now I need to display listing of document as per sharing done with users. W.r.t to above tables, as 'Folder 3' in Table 1 is child of 'Folder 2' which is child of 'Folder 1'.

Now only 'Folder 3' is shared with user '1234' (see in Table 2),  when document list will be shown as first of all only parents will be shown by default, in our case 'Folder 1'.

In my requirement I need to show only parents to be shown for navigation of child folder, as Folder one has one more child 'Document 1' and Folder 2 has one more child 'Document 2'.

But when i will open with User '1234' what I need to show is:

1. First page 'Folder 1'.
2. Clicking on 'Folder 1' shows only 'Folder 2' in it, not 'Document 1' as only 'Folder 3' is shared with user which comes under 'Folder 2'.
3. Now clicking on 'Folder 2' shows only 'Folder 3' in it, not 'Document 2' as only 'Folder 3' is shared with user.
4. Now Finally when we click on 'Folder 3' we will show all document and folder comes under 'Folder 3' as parent is shared with user.

I hope I am able to explain my problem. I need your help to prepare some query or a stored procedure to get required data efficiently. I am using MSSQL Server 2008 as database.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Show some efforts you have done so far.

Comment: @Monika : I have prepared one stored procedure for getting required data but that is only giving data of documents that is directly shared with user, I am unable to get result as per requirement. Unable to share Stored procedure here as it is prepared according to permissions assigned to logged in user and here I asked for logic by simplifying my tables to highlight issue. I am also working to prepare logic, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment, you are looking for a way to travers your folder structure from any child a user has rights for up to the root as well as everything below. So maybe a recursive query is what you are looking for?

Record user has rights on + everything above it:

```
WITH Child(id, name, parentId) AS 
(
    SELECT id, name, parentId 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM Table2 
                   WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.ShareDocId
                   AND   Table2.UserId = :userId )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Child.id, Child.name, Child.parentId
    FROM Table1 as Parent, Child
    WHERE Child.parentId = Parent.id
)
SELECT *
FROM Child
```

Record user has rights on + everything below it:

```
WITH Parent(id, name, parentId) AS 
(
    SELECT id, name, parentId 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM Table2 
                   WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.ShareDocId
                   AND   Table2.UserId = :userId )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Parent.id, Parent.name, Parent.parentId
    FROM Table1 as Child, Parent
    WHERE Child.parentId = Parent.id
)
SELECT *
FROM Child
```

Note: you will almost certainly get duplicate records (e.g. if someone has rights on multiple children of the same parent). Tweaking may be needed and a DISTINCT may be required.